# Problem with end{frontmatter} in elsarticle

Tags: elsarticle, front-matter

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,float,graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{ltxfront}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg,.png}

\modulolinenumbers[5]

\begin{document}

***\begin{frontmatter}***

\title{blah blah blah %\tnotetext[mytitlenote]{Fully documented templates are available in the elsarticle package on \href{http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle}{CTAN}.}

%% Group authors per affiliation:

\author{M.Sobhani Sanjabad}%\fnref{myfootnote}

\address{Razi University, Ardabil, Iran}
\author{T.Rajaeei}%\fnref{myfootnote}

\address{University of Qom, Qom, Iran}
\author{A.Dolatimehr}%\fnref{myfootnote}

\address{Istanbul Technical University}

\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{A.Dolatimehr}
\ead{Armin.dolati.mehr@gmail.com}

\begin{abstract}

blah blah blah ....

\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}

\texttt{elsarticle.cls} \sep forecasting \sep Genetic programming \sep wavelet \sep ANN method

\MSC[2010] 00-01\sep  99-00

\end{keyword}

\linenumbers

***\end{frontmatter}***
```

---

this error appears

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

 ***\end{frontmatter}***
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't load `titling` with `elsarticle`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't load packages that change the formatting, when using `elsarticle`, because the class is intended for submissions to Elsevier and they don't want strange or personalized titles or other elements.

In your case, avoid `titling` (and also `ltxfront` which is part of RevTeX).